# In Django/Python is there a is_model function?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django/Python is there a is_model function?

I want to determine if a value being read is a model, or a list of models...

For example

```
models = Models.object.all()
if is_model(models):
    print True
```

Comment: You could check if it's an instance of `QuerySet`.

Comment: How do I do that? Just like this, isinstance(obj, QuerySet)?

Comment: Yes, provided you've imported QuerySet correctly.

Answer (score 1):

use Python built in [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) `isinstance`.

Assuming your model class is Models:

```
if isinstance(models, QuerySet):
    #models is a list of Models
    pass

if isinstance(models, Models):
    #models is an instance of Models
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
models = Models.object.all()
```

returns always a `QuerySet`. I suppose you want to know if is composed by more than 1 record.

you can check with `len(models)` (but this is not performance friendly) or use `Models.object.count()`